# Laravel Vue Loading Side Bar Menu API

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I am getting menu like below from api request with laravel vue.

```
{"data":[{"id":67,"slug":"link","name":"Dashboard","href":"\/","hasIcon":true,"icon":"mdi mdi-home-account","iconType":"coreui","sequence":1}]}
```

and my componant is below and displaying well but click event not woking , when i mannully put this json data --> menu then every thing working good. so i think **mounted** is not working as per expectation in this senario. i tried like passing it from another component as props , then putting it in data --> menu but not working as well any idea ?

```
<template>
     <div class="vertical-menu">
                <div data-simplebar="init" class="h-100 mm-show">
                    <div id="sidebar-menu">
                        <ul class="metismenu list-unstyled" id="side-menu">
                                  <li v-for="(item, index) in menu" :key="index">
                                    <router-link :to="item.href ? item.href : ''" :class="item.slug === 'dropdown' ? 'has-arrow' : '' ">
                                        <i :class="item.icon"></i>
                                        <span :data-key="item.datakey">{{item.name}}</span>
                                    </router-link>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu" aria-expanded="false">
                                        <li v-for="subItem in item.elements" :key="subItem.name" > 
                                           <router-link :to="subItem.href  ? subItem.href : ''"> {{subItem.name}}  </router-link>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   name:"DashboardLeftBar",
   props:['app_base_url'],
   data(){
     return {
        menu: null
      }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.menuSideBar();   
    },
    methods:{
        menuSideBar(){
            let token= localStorage.getItem('jwt');
            let crl=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).crl;
            axios.post(myconstant.APPICATION_API_URL+'/getmenu',{
                token: token,
                crl: crl,
            }).then((response) => {
                this.menu = response.data.data;
               
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: First `this.menu = response.data.data;` makes your property non-reactive, therefore it won't rerender. You should use [this.$set()](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply , this.$set()  required  (object , key , value)  for to work , this.$set(this.menu,response.data.data); will not work here  ? how to set this one?

Comment: 1st prop is the object you want to modify. 2nd prop is the key you want access. 3rd prop is the value. So `this.$set(this, 'menu', response.data.data)` is the way.